# i need a regular field validator that accepts alphabets numbers `-. and only one space between words

Tags: regex, space

I have tried using ^[a-zA-Z0-9 `.]*$ . But it is allowing more spaces.And can anyone please explain what is "closed" in this context? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you could show some examples it will be better

Comment: I want it to validate these sample inputs Washington D.C., st-abcd ghij,    st abcd.efg`hi. And no spaces allowed in the beginning and at the end.

Comment: can you please check that input like "abcd hij.klmn`opqr" is giving an error. Thank you for the response. If it helps I am trying to validate cities in USA and Canada.

Comment: Can anyone please help me understand what CLOSED means in this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/^[a-z0-9\-\.`]+\s{0,1}[a-z0-9\-\.`]+$/gmi
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/vP4eX5/4)

Explaining:

```
^[a-z0-9\-\.\`]+       # starts with at least one letter/number/-/./`
\s{0,1}                # must or not contain one space - same as: '\s?'
[a-z0-9\-\.\`]+$       # ends with at least one letter/number/-/./`
```

Comment: this is allowing other non alphabetic characters. can you please show me how to allow only `-. in this same code?

Answer (score 1):

Your braces have a space in them and are also at the beginning of your regex after the carrot. so you need to exclude spaces at the beginning and end of text:

```
/^([a-z0-9\-]+\s{0,1}[a-z0-9\-]+)+$/gmi
```

you also want to include the '-' character by escaping it and including it.

https://regex101.com/

A nice website for testing regex

Answer (score 1):

This one should do a pretty good job:

```js
/*#!(?#!js valid Rev:20150715_1300)
    # Validate alphabets numbers `-. and only one space.
    ^                        # Anchor to start of string.
    (?=[^ ]+(?:[ ][^ ]+)*$)  # Only one space between words.
    [a-zA-Z0-9 `.-]*         # One or more allowed chars.
    $                        # Anchor to end of string.
!#*/
var valid = /^(?=[^ ]+(?: [^ ]+)*$)[a-zA-Z0-9 `.-]*$/;
```

Comment: This working great. And can you please explain me what closed in this context means?

Answer (score 0):

What I am interpreting from your question would look something like this.

`` ^([a-zA-Z0-9`.]+ ?)*[a-zA-Z0-9`.]+$ ``

It means that for every space in your string, there must be a series of the characters you suggested, and it must end with at least one of those characters as well.

Comment: I am sorry, but this one is not allowing spaces

Comment: Sorry, I guess the '?' was neccesary